# How to remove Leading white space inside XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <ItemID>01</ItemID>
    <ItemName>Book</ItemName>
  </item>
  <Product>
    <ProductID>01</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Paper</ProductName>
  </Product>
```

and want the output like this format to remove the leading white spaces from the beginning of `<product>` to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <ItemID>01</ItemID>
    <ItemName>Book</ItemName>
  </item><Product>
    <ProductID>01</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Paper</ProductName>
  </Product>
```

Can I do it in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you trying to achieve that? maybe are you better off minifying the whole content?

Comment: Actually I want to make it same of that shape to get same hash file result

Comment: fair enough, I posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be optimized in case it's a large file, but it will get you the idea:

```
<?php
$str = 'your xml content';
  
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
 
echo implode("\n", array_map(function ($line) {
    $trimmedLine = trim($line);
    
    if ($trimmedLine == "<Product>") {
        return $trimmedLine;
    }
    
    return $line;
}, $lines));
```

https://3v4l.org/2ab10

#### Edit:

for your updated version, you can do something like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $str);

$output = "";

$arrayLength = count($lines);

for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayLength; $i++) {
    $trimmedNextLine = isset($lines[$i + 1]) ? trim($lines[$i + 1]) : null;
    $line = $lines[$i];
    
    if ($trimmedNextLine == "<Product>") {
        $output .= $line . $trimmedNextLine;
        $i++;
    } else {
        $output .= $line;
    }
    
    if ($i < $arrayLength) {
        $output .= "\n";
    }
}

echo $output;
```

https://3v4l.org/pQSED

Comment: thanks bro, what if the XML content inside xml file?

Comment: depending on where you get the file from, you can read the file's content using [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). `$str = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/relative_path_to_the_xml_file.xml");` If you need to write it to a file later, you can use [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in DOM is a node, including the whitespace characters used for indentation. They are text nodes.

```php
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
  <item>
    <ItemID>01</ItemID>
    <ItemName>Book</ItemName>
  </item>
  <Product>
    <ProductID>01</ProductID>
    <ProductName>Paper</ProductName>
  </Product>
</products>
XML;

// bootstrap DOM
$document = new DOMDocument($xml);
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// fetch the whitespace text nodes preceding the "Product" elements
$expression = '//Product/preceding-sibling::node()[1][
  self::text() and normalize-space(.) = ""
]';

// iterate and remove
foreach($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $whitespace) {
  $whitespace->remove();
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```